# Is a weakly differentiable, $L^{2}$ function over $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Consider $u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}_{+})$. Is there always a bounded representative of $u$?

I have come across this sort of question multiple times, but I just cannot wrap my head around it. This is connected, at least from my point of view and from my experience, to this more generic question: given a function $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, for $p \neq \infty$, under which additional hypothesis (if any) is $u$ bounded?

I have often found myself with integrability hypotheses over unbounded sets such as $\mathbb{R}$ and have hoped to deduce some boundedness, but I can't think clearly about it.

Comment: $u(x) =\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)\cdot |x|^{-s}$, $s>0$,  are in $L^p$ (with a certain condition between $s$ and $p$), so $L^p$ functions are not bounded.

Comment: Of course, right. Thank you for the remark!

Answer (score 1):

We have the continuity of the embedding $W^{1,2}(0,1)$ into $C([0,1])$. That  is there is $c>0$ such that for all $u$
$$ 
\|u\|_{L^\infty(0,1)} \le c \|u\|_{W^{1,2}(0,1)} .
$$
This is true for all intervals of length $1$, so we can sum this up:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \|u\|_{L^\infty(n,n+1)}^2 \le c^2 \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \|u\|_{W^{1,2}(n,n+1)}^2 = c^2 \|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)}^2.
$$
Hence, the series on the left is converging, in particular $\|u\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)} \le  c \|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)}$.
Moreover, the series tells us that
$$
\lim_{|n|\to\infty}\|u\|_{L^\infty(n,n+1)}=0,
$$
i.e., $u$ kind of vanishes at infinity.